# How come the code stopped checking if is an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to write flatten an array, but how come it stopped checking when the code reached nested Array? It is out putting this `[ 1, 2, 3, [ [ [Object] ] ] ]`.

Please explain why it stopped going through nested Array and why it isn't concating. Thanks

```
flatten = function(nestedArray, result) {
    result = [];

    each(nestedArray, function(item){

      if(Array.isArray(item)){
          result = result.concat(item);
      } else {
          result.push(item);
      }
    });
return result;
};

flatten([1, [2], [3, [[[4]]]]])
```

Comment: You are not looping sub-dimensions, only first level of array

Comment: The code is just wrong. You need to call the `flatten` method recursively.

Comment: thanks guys! will do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no method like `each` in JavaScript, what you can do is use **[`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)** with [recursion function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Recursion).

```js
var flatten = function(nestedArray, result) {
  result = [];
  // iterate over array
  nestedArray.forEach(function(item) {
    if (Array.isArray(item)) {
      // do recursion to flatten the inner array and concatenate
      result = result.concat(flatten(item));
    } else {
      result.push(item);
    }
  });
  return result;
};

console.log(flatten([1, [2], [3, [[[4]]]]]));
```

Comment: @spaceDog : glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function pushfn(element,index, array){

if(Array.isArray(element)){
  element.forEach(pushfn);
}
else{
 result.push(element);
}

};

result = [];
var nestedArray = [1, [2], [3, [[[4]]]]];
nestedArray.forEach(pushfn);

console.log(result);
```